# .NET implementation of Portable Contacts API

Tags: .net, api, poco, opensocial, portable-contacts

Google just released a java implementation ([jpoco](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/poco/1.0/developers_guide.html)). Is there a .NET one?
Anyone planning on writing one?

Comment: Not AFAIK - but looks like it could be interesting to try... if only I had more time ;-(

Answer (score 3):

As Marc says, this would be an interesting thing to try. Fortunately, I can effectively make the time to work on this - it would be a reasonable 20% project if enough people are interested (so I can demonstrate it's adding value).

Please mail me (skeet@pobox.com) if this is something which you'd find useful, and I'll look into how much effort it would be. If it would only take a day or two to port, I may well be able to squeeze it in. Please don't feel that mailing me is redundant due to guessing that several other people will already have done so - the point is to gauge the usefulness of such a port.

If you could include `jpoco` in the subject line, that would help - I can set up a GMail label and filter to easily find them all.

Comment: I had a feeling you might spot this. I almost e-mailed you (to point it out), but then saw you were online anyway ;-p